# How do I edit the index page in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been googling, but I can't seem to find anything.

Where do I modify the index.php page?
This is the index.php:

```
     // Define path to application directory
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));

define('PUBLIC_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'library/Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'config.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

I've been looking inside the library folder, but there's alot of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index.php` script serves **every** request. I'm guessing what you actually want is the index page view script, which you can usually find at `application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml`. This is rendered within the default layout, which is probably at `application/layouts/default.phtml`.